# Change dynamically store location

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In order to have an accurate tax value by location during the checkout I would like to change dynamically my store location to the customer billing address. Is there a hook for that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are filters for store location that you can use to modify the output:

1. Base address first line: `woocommerce_countries_base_address`
2. Base address second line: `woocommerce_countries_base_address_2`
3. Base country: `woocommerce_countries_base_country`
4. Base state: `woocommerce_countries_base_state`
5. Base city: `woocommerce_countries_base_city`
6. Base postal code: `woocommerce_countries_base_postcode`

usage:

```
function custom_base_address( $base_address ){ 
   //your custom code to change base_address first line

    return $base_address
} 

add_filter('woocommerce_countries_base_address', 'custom_base_address', 10, 1)

function custom_base_city( $base_address ){ 
   //your custom code to change base state

    return $base_address
} 

add_filter('woocommerce_countries_base_state', 'custom_base_state', 10, 1)
```

And for customer billing address, you can get it from user meta. For example:

```
$address_1 = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'billing_address_1', true ); 
$address_2 = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'billing_address_2', true );
$city = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'billing_city', true );
$postcode = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'billing_postcode', true );
```

you can use these variables in a IF condition inside the custom_base_address function and get your desired custom base address

Comment: Thanks Naveen. I'm not so good in dev to create the full function but I will try.
The idea is to automatically change my store location with the customer billing address  so that the tax is calculated according to his address, and this for each order.